# Convert SQL Statement to Predicate or NSExpression

Tags: xcode, sqlite, core-data, nspredicate, nsexpression

I am facing a problem with converting below SQL to NSExpression

```
SELECT id,trait1,trait2,trait3,sum(trait1+trait2+trait3) as total FROM `bookings` GROUP BY id order by total desc
```

Below is my code in this code I am only able to add the two key values not three key values.

```
func aggregateProductsInContext(context:NSManagedObjectContext) {

    var expressionDescriptions = [AnyObject]()
    expressionDescriptions.append("name")

    let expressionDescription = NSExpressionDescription()
    expressionDescription.name = "Sold"

    let exp1 = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "trait1")
    let exp3 = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "trait2")
    let exp3 = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "trait3")

    let stas = NSExpression(forFunction:"add:to:", arguments:[exp1,exp3])

    expressionDescription.expression = stas
    expressionDescription.expressionResultType = .Integer64AttributeType
    expressionDescriptions.append(expressionDescription)
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "booking")
    request.propertiesToGroupBy = ["name"]
    request.resultType = .DictionaryResultType
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
    request.propertiesToFetch = expressionDescriptions



    var results:[[String:AnyObject]]?

    do {
        results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request) as? [[String:AnyObject]]
    } catch _ {
        results = nil
    }



print(results)

}
```

Please find the attached images of actual table values and resulted values for reference.

[image: ActualData image]

[image: Result Data after run the Sql query]

Thanks!

**My Solution:**

I am able to solve my problem by doing this

```
let ec = NSExpression(forFunction:"add:to:", arguments:[exp1,exp2])
let ec1 = NSExpression(forFunction:"add:to:", arguments:[ec,exp3])
let ec2 = NSExpression(forFunction:"add:to:", arguments:[ec1,exp4])
let ec3 = NSExpression(forFunction:"add:to:", arguments:[ec2,exp5])
```

If there is any other way to achieve this, please let me know

Thanks!

Comment: see this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/22398620/2031707

Comment: Have you considered using the `sum:` function with `NSExpression`?

Comment: @TomHarrington yes, and it only works on one column.

Comment: @Punita I don't want to do the Sum of all values of a column. I want to sum the multiple column values of one row

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution which I had implemented and it's work fine.

```
let ec = NSExpression(forFunction:"add:to:", arguments:[exp1,exp2])
let ec1 = NSExpression(forFunction:"add:to:", arguments:[ec,exp3])
let ec2 = NSExpression(forFunction:"add:to:", arguments:[ec1,exp4])
let ec3 = NSExpression(forFunction:"add:to:", arguments:[ec2,exp5])
```

But I am sure there must be some other good way to do that. If any one have any other solution. please let me know.

Thanks!